# Apache config: Is there a way to use “php-fpm” on all virtual hosts EXCEPT in two directories?

Tags: php, apache

Config: CentOS 7.7, php7.3 (remi), php-fpm

I have a couple of php based utils in subdirectories of different virtual hosts that are NOT happy when I use php-fpm.

One of the utils is calendar/caldav/Sabre based, even the login process does not work (not written by me). I am thinking of JUST bypassing php-fpm for this to save myself the hassle approaching the developer and waiting ....

To make it global for all virtual hosts I have in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf:

```
# Proxy declaration
<Proxy "unix:/var/run/php-fpm/default.sock|fcgi://php-fpm">
 # we must declare a parameter in here 
 # or it'll not register the proxy ahead of time
 ProxySet disablereuse=off
</Proxy>
# Redirect to the proxy
<FilesMatch \.php$>
 SetHandler proxy:fcgi://php-fpm
</FilesMatch>
```

It seems I backed myself into a corner how to exclude certain path (only two different directories)?

I have looked at LimitExcept etc but I cannot figure out how to put "For all directories/hosts but dir 'one' and dir 'two' use php-fpm in an apache/php config.

Comment: Read: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/  especially about the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION tips

Comment: Thanks, this works.